# Index out of bound in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have one bean AgreegateBean, which I am using as transfer object. Class definition for bean is as -

```
Class AgreegateBean {

 private SomeOtherBean bean;
 private List<Person> someList;

 // getters and setters
}
```

I am using this bean, in spring controller with ModelAttribute annotation. For the JSP, I am having JSTL. I have populated JSP with fields like this.

```
 <input type="text" name="someList[0].name" />
 <input type="text" name="someList[0].surName" />
```

when i am submitting my form I am getting **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0** .

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'someList[0]' of bean class [com.form.bean.AgreegateBean]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'someList[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are no elements in the retrieved `List<Person> someList;`

check it before:

```
<c:if test="${someList != null}">
    <input type="text" name="someList[0].name" />
    <input type="text" name="someList[0].surName" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because the OP mentions "submitting" the form. I think this is more Spring not creating new instances of `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution. Haven't used Generics in getters and setters. Don't know how, but adding generics fix the issue.